# Where is rc.lua called in Awesome WM?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, awesome-wm

I have installed awesome on Ubuntu 14.04 through apt-get. I can modify the rc.lua file just fine, but I'd like to know where it's called so that any print() statements I have in rc.lua can be teed to a log file.

I cannot find rc.lua in the default startx script, and I do not have a .xinitrc file. I'm assuming something must call the rc.lua, but how do I find out where it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/7ed29196bb8862ac7ef2cd7f07362a70acf58997/luaa.c#L584-L604

Awesome runs the `rc.lua` file during startup, so any `print()` statements go to awesome's stdout. How exactly do you start awesome? That's where you would have to do redirection?

Also, why do you want to redirect? Doesn't Ubuntu redirect this to `~/.xsession-errors` by default? Why do you need something different?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly I start awesome. When I did a apt-get install awesome, it simply appeared as an option in the login screen. That's why I'm not sure where rc.lua gets called. I was hoping it would be called in a shell script on bootup so I could use the tee util. I do not see output from print() appearing in ~/.xsession-errors

Comment: To followup, I was able to see error output appearing in ~/.xsession-errors so that should be enough for my purposes. I don't see print() appear there, but I do see output anytime I run io.stderr:write("message") appear there.